# forecast.Arima with xreg and the number of forecast periods

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to forecast values using `forecast.Arima` with argument `xtreg` and the number of forecast periods `h`.

My codes in R:

```
monthlylFatal <- ts(Spainmonthly$fatalities, start=c(1995,1), end= c(2013,12), frequency=12)
Spainpps <- ts(Spainmonthly$pps.2007, start=c(1995,1), end=c(2013,12), frequency=12)
Spainfinanc.cris <- ts(Spainmonthly$financ.cris.2008, start=c(1995,1), end=c(2013,12), frequency=12)
xreg <- cbind(Spainpps,Spainfinanc.cris)

arima1=Arima(logmonthlylFatal,order=c(0,1,1), seasonal=c(1,1,2), xreg = xreg)
forecast.arima1=forecast.Arima(arima1, xreg = xreg, h=84)
forecast.arima1
```

I want to forecast from January 2014 to December 2020 (`h=84`) but It forecasts more than I need (more than August 2030). I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always read the help file:

> h: Number of periods for forecasting. If xreg is used, h is ignored and the number of forecast periods is set to the number of rows of xreg.